# Know any alternative function names?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I know $e^x$ can be written as $exp(x)$ and $ln(x)$ can be written as $log_e(x)$. I wanted to know whether there are any alternative names/syntax for $sinh(x)$, $cosh(x)$, $|x|$, $|Re(z) + iIm(z)|$, etc. Alternate names for other functions are also welcome in the answers.

Comment: Another example is $\operatorname{Re}(z)\leftrightarrow\Re(z)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z) \leftrightarrow\Im(z)$. Not sure if you'd count these. Some people also use $\arcsin \leftrightarrow \sin^{-1}$ and similar things for other inverse trigonometric and inverse hyperbolic functions. I believe $\operatorname{tg}(x)$ is used for $\tan(x)$ by some people too, and $\operatorname{ctg}(x)$ for $\cot(x)$.

Comment: $|x|$ can be $\text{abs}(x)$ while $|\text{Re}(z) + i\,\text{Im}(z)|$ might be $|z|$

Comment: In some countries $\sinh z = \operatorname{sh} z$,  $\cosh z = \operatorname{ch} z$, such as $\arctan x=\operatorname{arctg} x$. Also I've seen $\sin x=\operatorname{sen} x$.

Comment: @Zacky And then $\text{atan}(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$ and $\tan^{-1}(x)$ are equivalent

Comment: @Henry that is right. I believe in computer science $\operatorname{atan} (x)$ is used often.

Answer (score 1):

Inverse trig functions have several alternate notations, e.g. $\tan^{-1}$, $\text{Tan}^{-1}$, $\arctan$, $\text{atan}$.